# Eset Smart security finds my hosts file as threat and quarantines it

Tags: security, anti-virus, hosts-file, eset

Everytime I edit my hosts file, Eset Smart security finds my hosts file as threat and quarantines it. It says the host files is a Qhost trojan.

What should I do?

Comment: What are you using to edit it with? What are you putting in / removing from it?

Comment: Notepad. Some adv sites.

Comment: Is this not something ESET should be helping with? It's a paid service, they have a support centre for this very reason.

Comment: Eset not so smart, use a different product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. 
When you add any site or server to 127.1.1.1 that caused the problem. 
For example:

```
127.1.1.1 superuser.com
```

Comment: Why would one do this?

Comment: @DaveM It's an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, when you know for sure that the AV is wrong, is to disable it while you are doing the work it's complaining about. I only recommend this if you are **100% sure you are doing something right**.

Once it's disabled, try editing your HOSTS file again. Save it, and close the `etc` folder, and the `HOSTS` file, then re-enable your AV. Does it complain again? Likely not

Comment: I've done that and still it complains. 

The only way it doesn't complain is by adding the file to the exclusion section of scan.

Comment: Then adding an exclusion is likely the only way you can do it. I'd be emailing their support though to ask *why* it's getting blocked by default from changing

Comment: @DSaad - So whats the problem?  ESET is detecting changes to the host file.  Their software engineers determined that modifications to this file should be detected as being possibly malicious if its modified.  Its not unusual for security software to complain about the hosts file being modified.

Comment: @CanadianLuke  
I found the problem. 
When you add any site or server to 127.1.1.1 that caused the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Look at the comment